# Change colour of Label.BTN

Tags: jquery, css

I am using bootstrap3 & fontawesome.  I have the following HTML:

```
<label for="foo" class='radio btn'>
    <input type="radio" id='foo' name='foo[]'>
    <span></span>
    Foo
</label>
```

With the followign CSS:

```
label.radio {background: #e8e8e8;font-size: 25px;text-align: center;width: 100%;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
label.radio.active {background:#f00;}
label.radio > input {display: none;}
label.radio > input+span:after {font-family: FontAwesome;content:"\f00d";}
label.radio > input:checked+span:after {font-family: FontAwesome;content:"\f00c";}
```

However I want to change the background of the label when it's clicked. I can't see a way to do this with CSS, so I tried jQuery:

```
$("label.radio").click(function (evt) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
})
```

But the `click()` function fires twice.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use checkbox change event to change the color of the label.

```
<label for="foo" id="fooLabel" class='radio btn'>
    <input type="radio" id='foo' name='foo[]'>
    <span></span>
    Foo
</label>

$('#foo').change(function() {
     $('#fooLabel').toggleClass("active")        
});
```

Comment: No sorry, this doesnt work.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it

Comment: Thanks, while I didn't actually go with this solution, the `.change()` on the radio actually was the key to me solving this.